# knockout dropdown error displaying data

Tags: knockout.js

```
Select Code: <select data-bind="options: violations, optionsText: desc, optionsValue: violCd">      </select>

<ul data-bind="foreach: violations">
   <li><span data-bind="text: violCd"></span></li>
</ul>


@section scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
<script type="text/javascript">

    function violation(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.violCd = data.violCd;
        self.desc = data.desc;
        self.amt = data.amt;
    }

    function MyViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.violations = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.loadToList = ko.computed(function() {
            alert('selected');
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Data/GetViolations",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $.each(data, function(i,val){
                    self.violations.push(new violation({ violCd: val.violCd, desc: val.desc, amt: val.amt }));
                });
            }
        });
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

</script>
```

}

If I comment out the select and just display the list - it's fine - but when I test the select I get an " Uncaught ReferenceError: violCd is not defined" error in chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
Select Code: <select data-bind="options: violations, 
                            optionsText: function(item) {
                                return item.desc
                            }, 
                            optionsValue: function(item) { return item.violCd; }"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is add a quotes around the parameters like this:- 'desc' and 'violCd'

```
Select Code: <select data-bind="options: violations, optionsText: 'desc', optionsValue: 'violCd'">      </select>
```